# SimpleDateFormat is not interpreting %g

Tags: simpledateformat

```
final String LOG_FILENAME =
 new SimpleDateFormat("'tool_'yyyyMMddHHmmss_SSS_'%g.log'").format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
String logFilePtrn = new StringBuilder(System.getProperty("user.dir")).append(System.getProperty("file.separator")).append(LOG_FILENAME).toString();
```

when I print the log file it prints like this
Log file location:/tool/log/tool_20140625155513_309_%g.log

but actual log file that got generated was tool_20140625161235_309_0.log

any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What would you expect `SimpleDateFormat` to do with `%g`?

Comment: i wanted to print the log file name as it was generated. i.e intercept %g with 0 in the example

Comment: My question remains: what piece of logic in your code do you expect to actually replace the `%g` with `0`?

Comment: when i print the name of the log file using lgr.info(MessageFormat.format("Log file location:{0}",                         logFilePtrn));  it is printing with %g instead of the 0.  but when i open the log file using the same logfilePtrn it is opening with proper name. fileHndlr = new FileHandler(logFilePtrn);

Comment: Re- phrasing my issue. I am using the file name pattern as final String LOG_FILENAME = new StringBuilder(System.getProperty("user.dir")).append(System.getProperty("file.separator")).append(LOG_FILNAME).toString(); when I print this file pattern i am getting Tool_20140627115446_451_%g.log But when I open the log file using the same pattern fileHndlr = new FileHandler(logFilePtrn, 1048576, 100); it is opening the logfile name with Tool_20140627115446_451_0.log. Any thoughts.